# Sort edges in BFS/DFS

Tags: python, sorting, graph

I am working a problem of sorting edges, where edges are stored in a tuple form `(node_i, node_j)` like below

```
>> edgeLst
>> [('123','234'),
    ('123','456'),
    ('123','789'),
    ('456','765'),
    ('456','789')
    ('234','765')]
```

Note that edges are unique, and if you see `('123', '234')`, you won't see `('234', '123')` (the graph is undirected). And there might be a loop in the graph. Since the graph is very large, can anyone show me the efficient way to sort edges in BFS and DFS with a given start node, e.g., `'123'`?

Demo output:

```
>> edgeSorting(input_lst=edgeLst, by='BFS', start_node='123')
>> [('123','234'),
    ('123','456'),
    ('123','789'),
    ('234','765')
    ('456','765'),
    ('456','789')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it for BFS and DFS:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def sorted_edges(input_lst, by, start_node):
    # Key the edges by the vertices
    vertices = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for u, v in input_lst:
        vertices[u].append(v)
        vertices[v].append(u)
    if by == 'DFS':
        # Sort the lists
        for lst in vertices:
            lst = sorted(lst)
        # Perform DFS
        visited = set()
        def recurse(a):
            for b in vertices[a]:
                if not (a, b) in visited:
                    yield ((a,b))
                    # Make sure this edge is not visited anymore in either direction
                    visited.add((a,b))
                    visited.add((b,a))
                    for edge in recurse(b):
                        yield edge
        for edge in recurse(start_node):
            yield edge
    else: #BFS
        # Collect the edges
        visited = set()
        queue = [start_node]
        while len(queue):
            for a in queue: # Process BFS level by order of id
                level = []
                for b in vertices[a]:
                    if not (a, b) in visited:
                        yield ((a,b))
                        # Add to next level to process
                        level.append(b)
                        # Make sure this edge is not visited anymore in either direction
                        visited.add((a,b))
                        visited.add((b,a))
            queue = sorted(level)


edgeLst = [('123','234'),
('123','456'),
('123','789'),
('456','765'),
('456','789'),
('234','765')]

print (list(sorted_edges(edgeLst, 'DFS', '123')))
```

In Python 3, you can simplify:

```
for edge in recurse(b):
    yield edge
```

to:

```
yield from recurse(b)
```

... and same for `start_node`.

Comment: Why there is `yield from recurse(123)` and `queue=['123']`? I don't think we need to include any specific information like `'123'` in the function.

Comment: I am currently using Python 2.7. Can you give me a hint how to replace `yield from` such that the above code can work?

Comment: `for edge in recurse(b):
                        yield edge`. Similar for the call with `start_node`.

Comment: What if the graph has several components? Each component is not connecting to others. For example `edgeLst = [('123','345'), ('345', '456'), ('999','012')]`. The solution can only return `[('123', '345'), ('345', '456')]`.

Comment: DFS and BFS starting from a given node can by their definition never reach anything that is not connected to the given node. In that case you should define how you want to visit and sort. You could for instance extend the function so that it accepts multiple starting nodes, one for each disconnected part of the graph.